# How to render mist path as png sequence in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Is there any way to do this? Stil mist path image is cool but I need 2000 frames of it to control the depth of field of my animation dynamicly.

Comment: *Render > Render Animation*? `Ctrl` + `F12` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that you don't have to render your animation twice, you can output as many passes or composites as you like at the same time using a [File Output node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/file.html?highlight=file%20output): 
[image]

SHIFT A -> Output -> File Output

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple. In compositor layout do this.

[image]

And here is the tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0JtiByzBkQ&ab_channel=PIXXO3D